# XSLT : Cummulative Sum (Conditional)

Tags: xslt

I need to do a conditional sum using XSLT. The sum of 'Oty' for each 'SKU' should be calculated only for providers listed within the 'Provider' node. In the provided example, the Qty for providerCode 4 should be skipped as its not in the 'Providers' list. I'm restricted to using XSLT 1.0.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is the sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Providers>
        <ProviderCode>1</ProviderCode>
        <ProviderCode>2</ProviderCode>
        <ProviderCode>3</ProviderCode>        
    </Providers>
    <SKU>
        <SKU>XYZ</SKU>
        <Description>XYZ Description</Description>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>1</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>100</Qty>
        </Provider>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>2</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>67</Qty>
        </Provider>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>3</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>74</Qty>
        </Provider>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>4</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>62</Qty>
        </Provider>    
    </SKU>
    <SKU>
        <SKU>ABC</SKU>
        <Description>ABC Description</Description>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>1</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>20</Qty>
        </Provider>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>2</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>77</Qty>
        </Provider>
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>3</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>42</Qty>
        </Provider>    
        <Provider>
            <ProviderCode>4</ProviderCode>
            <Qty>631</Qty>
        </Provider>    
    </SKU>    
</Root>
```

Here is the required output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <SKU>
        <SKU>XYZ</SKU>
        <Qty>241</Qty>
    </SKU>
    <SKU>
        <SKU>ABC</SKU>
        <Qty>139</Qty>
    </SKU>    
</Root>
```

Comment: And the code xslt?. would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `sum` on the nodes you want, either by comparing `sum(Provider[ProviderCode = //Providers/ProviderCode]/Qty)` or by using a key:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="prov" match="Providers/ProviderCode" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SKU"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Root/SKU">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="SKU"/>
    <Qty><xsl:value-of select="sum(Provider[key('prov', ProviderCode)]/Qty)"/></Qty>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: +1 good answer. One small typo in your opening paragraph: that XPath should be `sum(Provider[ProviderCode = //Providers/ProviderCode]/Qty)` .

Comment: Great!! With the latest change sum(Provider[ProviderCode = //Providers/ProviderCode]/Qty), the sum value is correct. Thanks again!!

Comment: @user2554529, the inline path sample was incorrect, but the complete code sample with the key solution has been correct in the first version of the answer and is more efficient anyway.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I've posted another question at <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531066/xslt-sum-multiple-conditions> that uses your answer as the 'base'. It would be great if you provide your comments in it. Thanks!. P.S: I couldn't post it as comment here as the code sample exceeds the number of chars.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Thanks for your help with these questions. I've accepted your answer.