# XSLT Sum (multiple conditions)

Tags: xslt

I used the answer at [XSLT : Cummulative Sum (Conditional)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17494261/xslt-cummulative-sum-conditional) as 'base' to do the sum on a different xml and I'm not getting the correct sum.

The output should be created for only the 'skus' within Root/Items/Result/Sku. The cummulative sum should be grouped by 'Provider Quality' (main, damaged) for the only the providers within Root/Providers/Result/

I'm sure that my predicate condition within the sum is wrong. But I'm not able to figure out the issue. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Items>
        <Result>
            <Sku>XYZ</Sku>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Sku>ABC</Sku>
        </Result>
    </Items>
    <Providers>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Main</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>1_D</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Main</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
        </Result>
    </Providers>
    <Message>
        <Body>
            <Inventory>
                <SKU>
                    <SKU>AXYZ</SKU>
                    <Description>XYZ Description</Description>
                    <Providers>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>100</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>67</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>75</Qty>
                        </Provider>                        
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>3_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>74</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>4</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>62</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                    </Providers>
                </SKU>
                <SKU>
                    <SKU>ABC</SKU>
                    <Description>ABC Description</Description>
                    <Providers>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>20</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>205</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>77</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>5</Qty>
                        </Provider>                        
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>3_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>42</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>4_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>631</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                    </Providers>
                </SKU>    
            </Inventory>
        </Body>
    </Message>
</Root>
```

XSLT used:

```
    <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="validProviders" match="/Root/Providers/Result" use="ProviderCode"/>
    <xsl:key name="validProviderQuality" match="/Root/Providers/Result" use="Quality"/>
    <xsl:key name="inboundSkus" match="/Root/Message/Body/Inventory/SKU" use="SKU"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/Root/Items/Result"/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/Items/Result">
        <xsl:if test="key('inboundSkus',Sku)">
            <SKU>
                <xsl:variable name="Sku" select="Sku"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Providers/Result[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('validProviderQuality',Quality)[1])]">
                    <Record>
                        <xsl:variable name="ProviderQuality" select="Quality" />
                        <xsl:element name="Sku"><xsl:value-of select="$Sku"/></xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Quality"><xsl:value-of select="$ProviderQuality"/></xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Qty1"><xsl:value-of select="sum(/Root/Message/Body/Inventory/SKU[SKU=$Sku]/Providers/Provider[ProviderCode=/Root/Providers/Result[Quality=$ProviderQuality]]/Qty)"/></xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="Qty2"><xsl:value-of select="sum(/Root/Message/Body/Inventory/SKU[SKU=$Sku]/Providers/Provider[key('validProviderQuality',$ProviderQuality)]/Qty)"/></xsl:element>
                    </Record>                        
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SKU>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <SKU>
        <Record>
            <Sku>ABC</Sku>
            <Quality>Main</Quality>
            <Qty1>0</Qty1>
            <Qty2>980</Qty2>
        </Record>
        <Record>
            <Sku>ABC</Sku>
            <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
            <Qty1>0</Qty1>
            <Qty2>980</Qty2>
        </Record>
    </SKU>
</Root>
```

Wanted result is

```
<Root>
  <SKU>
    <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Main</Quality>
      <Qty>97</Qty>
    </Record>
    <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
      <Qty>210</Qty>
    </Record>
  </SKU>
</Root>
```

Comment: Have you posted the result you want or the one you currently get?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, The posted output is the result that I currently get. The needed result is   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Root>
        <SKU>
            <Record>
                <Sku>ABC</Sku>
                <Quality>Main</Quality>
                <Qty>97</Qty>
            </Record>
            <Record>
                <Sku>ABC</Sku>
                <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
                <Qty>210</Qty>
            </Record>
        </SKU>
    </Root>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a adaption of your stylesheet as xslt-1.0 solution.
You may try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output  method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="validProviderQuality" match="/Root/Providers/Result" use="Quality"/>

    <xsl:variable name="mySkus" select="//Result/Sku" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Root>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                   select="/Root/Message/Body/Inventory/SKU[SKU = $mySkus]"/>
        </Root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root/Message/Body/Inventory/SKU" >

        <xsl:variable name="Sku" select="SKU"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Providers/Result[generate-id(.)= 
                                  generate-id(key('validProviderQuality',Quality)[1])]">
            <SKU>
                <Record>
                    <xsl:variable name="ProviderQuality" select="Quality" />
                    <xsl:element name="Sku">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Sku"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Quality">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ProviderQuality"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:element name="Qty">
                        <xsl:value-of 
                           select="sum(//SKU[SKU=$Sku]//Provider[
                                          ProviderCode=/Root/Providers/Result[
                                            Quality=$ProviderQuality
                                          ]/ProviderCode
                                        ]/Qty)"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </Record>
            </SKU>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <SKU>
    <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Main</Quality>
      <Qty>97</Qty>
    </Record>
  </SKU>
  <SKU>
    <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
      <Qty>210</Qty>
    </Record>
  </SKU>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for modified solution. It works perfect. I couldn't vote it up as I don't have enough 'reputation'.

Answer (score 0):

I think the requirement is pretty complicated, to understand it better I have tried to implement it in XSLT 2.0. I don't have time to try to implement it in XSLT 1.0 however, so I will post the XSLT 2.0 code (you could run with an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML):

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="wanted-skus" select="/Root/Items/Result/Sku"/>

<xsl:variable name="wanted-prvdrs" select="/Root/Providers/Result/ProviderCode"/>

<xsl:key name="qual" match="Root/Providers/Result" use="ProviderCode"/>

<xsl:template match="Root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group 
     select="Message/Body/Inventory/SKU
              [SKU = $wanted-skus]
              /Providers/Provider[ProviderCode = $wanted-prvdrs]"
          group-by="key('qual', ProviderCode)/Quality">      
           <Record>
             <Sku><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::SKU/SKU"/></Sku>
             <Quality><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></Quality>
             <Qty><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Qty)"/></Qty>
           </Record>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>       

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using that stylesheet Saxon 9.5 transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <Items>
        <Result>
            <Sku>XYZ</Sku>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <Sku>ABC</Sku>
        </Result>
    </Items>
    <Providers>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Main</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>1_D</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Main</Quality>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
            <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
        </Result>
    </Providers>
    <Message>
        <Body>
            <Inventory>
                <SKU>
                    <SKU>AXYZ</SKU>
                    <Description>XYZ Description</Description>
                    <Providers>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>100</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>67</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>75</Qty>
                        </Provider>                        
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>3_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>74</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>4</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>62</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                    </Providers>
                </SKU>
                <SKU>
                    <SKU>ABC</SKU>
                    <Description>ABC Description</Description>
                    <Providers>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>20</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>1_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>205</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>77</Qty>
                        </Provider>
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>2_D</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>5</Qty>
                        </Provider>                        
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>3_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>42</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                        <Provider>
                            <ProviderCode>4_M</ProviderCode>
                            <Qty>631</Qty>
                        </Provider>    
                    </Providers>
                </SKU>    
            </Inventory>
        </Body>
    </Message>
</Root>
```

into the wanted result

```
<Root>
   <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Main</Quality>
      <Qty>97</Qty>
   </Record>
   <Record>
      <Sku>ABC</Sku>
      <Quality>Damaged</Quality>
      <Qty>210</Qty>
   </Record>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the XSLT 2.0 based solution. This is exactly the requirement. But, unfortunately I'm restricted to 1.0. Can you identify the predicate issue with the original XSLT solution?